# flutter Create arrow on the side of TabBar depending on the current index

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm currently learning about making tabBar. I wanted to achieve something like the image below, where on my current active tab there will be an arrow indented towards the other inactive tab. How can I achieve this ? Should I use stack ? And I also need this to be responsive on different screen.

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  controller: collabTabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  labelStyle: weight500Style,
                  unselectedLabelColor: defaultProfileColor,
                  unselectedLabelStyle: weight500Style,
                  indicator: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                        selectedTabIndex == 0
                            ? const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                        )
                            : const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                        )
                    ),
                    color: selectedTabIndex == 0 ? personalCardTag : Colors.orange,
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text:'text 1'.tr()),
                    Tab(text:'text 2'.tr()),
                  ],
                ),
                RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: Triangle(),
                    child: Container(
                      color: formBackgroundColor,
                      width: 40,
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: I think you should try using image with stack over the tabbar, that would be the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class TabBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabBarPage> createState() => _TabBarPageState();
}

class _TabBarPageState extends State<TabBarPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int selectedTabIndex = 0;
  TabController? collabTabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    collabTabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double ScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          children: [
            TabBar(
              controller: collabTabController,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
              onTap: (value) {
                selectedTabIndex = value;
                setState(() {});
              },
              indicator: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: selectedTabIndex == 0
                        ? const BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                          )
                        : const BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          )),
                color: selectedTabIndex == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.orange,
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'text 1'),
                Tab(text: 'text 2'),
              ],
            ),
            selectedTabIndex == 0
                ? Positioned(
                    left: ScreenWidth * 0.5,
                    child: RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: selectedTabIndex == 0 ? 0 : 2,
                      child: ClipPath(
                        clipper: Triangle(),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48,
                          width: 40,
                          color: selectedTabIndex == 0
                              ? Colors.amber
                              : Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Positioned(
                    right: ScreenWidth * 0.5,
                    child: RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: 2,
                      child: ClipPath(
                        clipper: Triangle(),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48,
                          width: 40,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Triangle extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.8, size.height * 0.4)
      ..cubicTo(size.width * 0.8, size.height * 0.4, size.width,
          size.height * 0.5, size.width * 0.8, size.height * 0.6)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: describe the code